# Evaluate each field in Python function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying evaluate each field in the if statement below.

However, I am running into the following error: **Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist**.

What I am trying to achieve: I am trying to evaluate two fields in my dataframe - Name and Surname, in a Python function. In these fields, I have NULL values. For each field, I would like to identify if NULL values exist.

I am loading various datasets with fields that should be evaluated from each set. I would like to pass these fields into the function to check if NULL values exist.

```
def identifyNull(Field):

Field = ['Name', 'Surname'] - this is an example of what I would like to pass to my function. 

for x in Field:
  if df.select().filter(col(Field).isNull()).count() > 0:
    print(Field)
  else:
    print('False')
```

df = the dataframe name for the data I am reading.

df structure:

| Name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| John | Doe |
| NULL | James |
| Lisa | NULL |

Please note: I am completely new to Python and Spark.

Comment: What is df exactly?

Comment: @Stefan df = the dataframe name for the data I am reading. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Did you mean `if df.select().filter(col( x).isNull()).count() > 0:` and then `print(x)`? (Otherwise what would be the point interating your `Field` list?

Comment: @JNevill I would like to pass the two fields in the function. I am loading various datasets with fields that should be evaluated from each set. I would like to pass these fields into the function to check if NULL values exist.

Comment: Right. You want to pass each field, one at a time into the function, but you are passing the list into the function. `x` is your field. Your `for` loop is saying *"Take each item in this list called `fields` and call that item `x`"*. Many programming languages use the syntax `For Each x in fields` which is a little clearer. Python just drops the `Each` so it isn't so verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
data = [["John", "Doe"], 
        [None, "James"],
        ["Lisa", None]]
Field = ["Name", "Surname"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, Field)
df.show()
```

returns:

```
+----+-------+
|Name|Surname|
+----+-------+
|John|    Doe|
|null|  James|
|Lisa|   null|
+----+-------+
```

Then

```py
for x in Field:
    if df.select(x).where(x+" is null").count()>0:
        print(x)
    else:
        print(False)
```

returns:

```
Name
Surname
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `col(Field)` with Field is a list. Since you're looping through fields, try with `col(x)` instead.

So it'd be something like this:

```py
for x in Field:
    if df.where(F.col('Name').isNull()).count() > 0:
        print(x)
    else:
        print('False')
```